# Preventing IDOR Attacks Using Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: c#, .net-core, attributes, aop

I'm looking for a way to prevent insecure direct object reference ([IDOR](https://blog.detectify.com/2016/05/25/owasp-top-10-insecure-direct-object-reference-4/)) attacks, using AOP, so I don't need to add code to every API controller method to check it.

An example of an IDOR attack would be to intercept the request and change the body of the request so that the object's `CompanyId`, and other properties, are different to try and insert a record to a different company (other than the company to which the user belongs -- specified in the JWT).

The problem is that each method accepts its own parameters as different classes. For example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAdjustment(Adjustment adjustment)
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateHistory(History history)
```

So the common code would need to know how to check an `adjustment` object and a `history` object. Each parameter has a `CompanyId` property on it. And that second method could compare the `CompanyId` property on `history` with the `CompanyId` in the JWT (and thrown an exception if they're different).

I just don't want to have to add that same code to every API controller method, like this:

```
    var companyClaim = HttpContext.User.Claims
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Consts.Claims.CompanyId);
    
    if (companyClaim == default) { return Unauthorized(); }
    
    if (Convert.ToInt32(companyClaim.Value) != history.CompanyId)
        { return Unauthorized(); }
```

Perhaps have every DTO/domain parameter implement something like `ICompanyWhatever` to signify it will have a `CompanyId` property?  Then the AOP code could check each parameter the same way?

The problem I'm having is that attributes don't have access to the method's parameters. Or do they? Is there a way to get that from an attribute? If not, perhaps use interception?

Comment: I'm looking into IActionFilter now. It executes after model binding, but before the action method has been executed. This may be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post a working example. I'm sure I'll tweak this to make it better, but it answers my question, above. I also may move it to be an action attribute, but we'll see.

Basically, I'm just getting the company ID from claims, then comparing it to the API controller's parameters. If the parameter has CompanyId on it, we compare its value to what's in claims. If they don't match, throw an exception.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using SomeDepartment.SomeProject.Shared.Common;

namespace ReadyTime.TimeOff.Shared.Infrastructure.Filters
{
    public class CompanyValidationActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var companyClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Consts.Claims.CompanyId);

            if (companyClaim == default) { throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Company claim not found."); }

            long claimCompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(companyClaim.Value);

            // Make sure every method parameter object, that has a CompanyId property, matches in value with the
            // company ID in claims.
            foreach (var argument in context.ActionArguments)
            {
                PropertyInfo companyIdProperty = argument.Value.GetType().GetProperty("CompanyId",
                    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                
                if (companyIdProperty == default) { continue; } // Not an object with a CompanyId property, so ignore.

                long companyIdPropertyAsLong = (long)Convert.ChangeType(companyIdProperty.GetValue(argument.Value),
                    TypeCode.Int64);

                if (companyIdPropertyAsLong != claimCompanyId)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("The CompanyId value on the parameter does not match claims.");
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // do nothing
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other choice about AOP:
you just need interceptor controller to do filter, see the console demo below

```
// 1
public class ConsoleInterceptor : AbstractInterceptor
 {
     public override async Task InvokeAsync(AspectContext context, AsyncAspectDelegate next)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"{context.Service.GetType().GetReflector().FullDisplayName}.{context.Method.GetReflector().DisplayName}");
         await next(context);
     }
 }

 // 2
 [ApiController]
 [Route("[controller]")]
 public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public virtual IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get() => test.Get();
 }

 // 3
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
     services.ConfigureAop(i => i.GlobalInterceptors.Add(new ConsoleInterceptor()));
 }
```

You will see the following output in the console:
`Norns.Urd.DynamicProxy.Generated.WeatherForecastController_Proxy_Inherit.IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()`